# How to test whether the browser can play avi format video?

Tags: javascript, html, html5-video

The `canPlayType` could be used for `video/mp4`, `video/webm`, etc.

But how to test whether the browser can play `avi` format video?

`canPlayType('x-msvideo')` will not work, even if the avi file could be played.

```
var a = document.createElement('video')
a.canPlayType('video/mp4'); // 'maybe'
a.canPlayType('video/webm'); // 'maybe'
a.canPlayType('application/x-troff-msvideo'); // ''
a.canPlayType('video/x-msvideo') // ''
a.canPlayType('video/msvideo') // ''
a.canPlayType('video/avi') // ''
```

Comment: Why not just convert the container format to a type which is commonly supported?

Comment: @robertc There is tons of videos and I don't have that space to hold them all, so I'm thinking about doing some real-time transcoding.

Comment: Chances are you don't need to do any transcoding, just change the container format.

Comment: @robertc Thanks, you are right about that.

Answer (score 1):

Well, it seems that I was fooled by the file extension name, the video format actually is `QuickTime / MOV`, so it could be played by the browser, I changed their name now everything works fine.

Anyway, we could use the `video` `canplay` event, just set the src, then check whether the `canplay` event fired.